# Sum of products for each row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Given a table with two columns, A and B:

For each row, multiply A and B, then sum all the results.

I can just do `=(A1*B1)+(A2*B2)+...` but I need it to work for a table of any size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is exactly what SUMPRODUCT is for:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5,B1:B5)
```

Comment: Thanks! For a table then, its as simple as =SUMPRODUCT([column1],[column2])

Comment: @JaredTritsch Instead of showing "Thanks" in a comment, simply click the green arrow on the answer to show that it works for you.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I answered too quickly Jared must wait till the question is 15 minutes old.

Comment: @JaredTritsch yup, that simple.

Comment: Is that really a thing? No wonder why most of my accepted answers never go accepted :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the array version of sum.  This can give some added flexability in certain situations.

{=SUM(A1:A5*B1:B5)}